# Deny access to multiple files in htaccess

Tags: php, html, file, .htaccess

I'd like to deny multiple files through htaccess.

```
<FilesMatch (profile|reg|register|..............|)\.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I have lots of files (6 folders with like 30 files each) that I want to deny access to, so using the method above by entering them one by one will take time.

Could I deny access to all files in the folders like this?

```
<Directory /www/php/login/pages>
  Order Allow,Deny
</Directory>
```

Comment: The manual knows all: [<Directory> Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  Also, why put these scripts in the web root at all, if you are denying access to them?  It is common practice to only put what is needed in the web root, and leave the rest of the application elsewhere.

Comment: best solution is to simply have these files OUTSIDE of the document root. php can still include/require them, since it's not bound by the apache-level restrictions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To multiple

```
<FilesMatch "(foo|bar|doo)\.php$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

or go for rewrite rules (`RewriteEngine On`)

```
RewriteRule \.(psd|log)$ - [NC,F]
```

To deny access to all files in the folders:

```
rewriteRule ^www/php/login/pages - [NC,F]
```

or simply place a `Deny from all' directly in that folder...

**Update 2015:** Using Apache 2.4 or higher, the `Deny from all' [would needs adjustment](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add "deny from all" like your initial approach, but yes you can.

Scroll down in the documentation for the syntax you are looking for: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: From the page you are quoting: `Note that unlike <Directory> and <Location> sections, <Files> sections can be used inside .htaccess files.` ==> no <Directory> in .htaccess